# How to turn off notification in Android Studio to set proxy configuration in the project's gradle.properties file?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm switching our project from Eclipse to Android Studio. I had the proxy settings in our project's gradle.properties file, but then I realized that I have to check this file into version control and it would expose my passwords.

I moved these settings to [USER_HOME]/.gradle/gradle.properties and it works fine, except for Android Studio asks at every gradle sync if I want to copy the configuration back to the project folder.

How do I turn this notification off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `${idea.config.path}/options/options.xml` file, there is a  `/application/component[@name='PropertiesComponent']/property[@name='show.do.not.copy.http.proxy.settings.to.gradle']` element node.

- If its value is true(default value), "Proxy Settings" dialog will be shown normally;

  `<property name="show.do.not.copy.http.proxy.settings.to.gradle" value="true" />`
- if its value is false, Android Studio will "do not ask again".

  `<property name="show.do.not.copy.http.proxy.settings.to.gradle" value="false" />`

> **Tips**:
>
> - Don't forget to click Synchronize(Ctrl+Alt+Y) button or File->Synchronize, after change this file.
> - `idea.config.path` is set in `android-studio\bin\idea.properties`, whose default value is `${user.home}/.AndroidStudio${version}/config`

---

*Tested with Android Studio 1.4 Preview 2 @ Win8.1 X64*

Comment: I think they fixed this issue by adding this flag around AS 1.3 Beta, after I added a ticket to the AS project. this is probably not a complete solution, but it works for me. I'm afraid I couldn't track this because the switch was postponed by my employer and I was busy with other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In 1.3 version of Android studio there is a checkbox "do not ask again". And that exactly is the problem I'm having. I've checked it because everything was functioning OK without it but now I'd like to bring that dialog back as for the past couple of days the projects don't compile because gradle can not resolve new dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This setting `<property name="show.do.not.copy.http.proxy.settings.to.gradle" value="true" />` could also be located in your project's folder in the file `.idea\workspace.xml`.